# Ansible setup "Magic Variables"

Tags: variables, installation, ansible

I am new to ansible (1 to 2 months) and all ready have the majority of configuration / setup tasks migrated to ansible.  I am seeing inconsistencies with ansible_domain variable on my servers.  Can anybody tell me what setting(s) on the client machine is used to populate the ansible_domain variable so that I can rectify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain is basically gathered by this python snippet:

```
'.'.join(socket.getfqdn().split('.')[1:])
```

Or in words, the string behind the last `.` or in case there is no `.`, the whole string.

From the docs of [socket.getfqdn()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.getfqdn):

> Return a fully qualified domain name for name. If name is omitted or empty, it is interpreted as the local host. To find the fully qualified name, the hostname returned by gethostbyaddr() is checked, followed by aliases for the host, if available. The first name which includes a period is selected. In case no fully qualified domain name is available, the hostname as returned by gethostname() is returned.

The full code is here
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/d49b11e9962df4bde4b8f3d61029305af4115748/lib/ansible/module_utils/facts.py#L183

Comment: some of the machine /etc/hosts file were messed up. 127.0.0.1               localhost
127.0.0.1       myserver.domain.local myserver
192.168.1.10    myserver.domain.local myserver.  I removed the following line "127.0.0.1       myserver.domain.local myserver" and it has resolved my problems.  Thank you for point me in the correct direction.